# Calabash-android color logging?

Tags: android

I feel like this should be a pretty simple thing but how can I display color output in the console logging?

```
When /^I log in$/ do
    p "Press the login button"
    tap_when_element_exists("* id:'btn_login'")
    macro 'I enter dynamic "EMAIL" into field with id "et_name"'
    macro 'I enter dynamic "PASS" into field with id "et_pwd"'
    p "Press the login button"
    tap_when_element_exists("* id:'btn_login'")
    p "Wait for something to load"
    wait_for_element_exists("* id:'lv_inbox'")
end
```

This is crummy because each of those messages prints and then afterwards you get one pretty green line that reads "When I log in". What would be better is if it printed "When I log in" first and then all of the sub-steps print in color, indented afterwards.

I tried to figure out how to use the color_helper.rb but was unsuccessful. I tried things like 'red "my message"' which doesn't give an error but it also doesn't print anything!